# Fixed Background web page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was implementing this web page http://dreamywatches.co.uk/index.html (dont mind the url its for testing)  but my boss want to have the contents in the center and have a fixed background like this website http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html

what is the best and simple way to go forward with this in bootstrap? Please let me know

Comment: Pretty good solutions there: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In you CSS, Add background-size: cover.

body {

> background: url('yourimage') no-repeat center center fixed; 
>   -webkit-background-size: cover;
>    -moz-background-size: cover;
>    -o-background-size: cover;
>    background-size: cover;
>   color:#fff;
>       background-color:#fff;

}